# включение/отключение интернета по нажатию клавиши

Tags: python

Как выключить или включить интернет по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

В `Windows` можно отключить интернет  через коммандную строку.

Команда выглядит так:

```
ipconfig/release
```

Следовательно мы можем её выполнить средствами `Python`, при помощи `os.system()`.

Конечный код выглядит так:

```py
import os 
print('disable internet now on windows')
os.system('ipconfig/release') 
print('internet disabled')
```

---

Есть второй вариант — если известен адаптер, через который идёт доступ в интернет, то можно попробовать через эту команду:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLE
```

И код тогда выглядит так:

```py
import os 
print('disable internet now on windows')
os.system('netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLE') 
print('internet disabled')
```

---

Кстати, если Вы неплохо понимаете английский, то [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/846501/how-can-i-disable-internet-access-on-windows-7-via-the-command-line) обсуждение, как это сделать это на `Windows`
А [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/523490/how-to-shut-off-all-networking-on-linux-from-bash/523497) — как это сделать на `Linux`.

И выполняйте команды через `os.system` в `Python`.

Надеюсь, это поможет! Удачи Вам!

Comment: Если на интерфейсе прописан статический адрес, эта команда ничего не сделает.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо огромное!